# What does the colon dash ":-" mean in bash

Tags: bash, shell, syntax, semantics

The result is the one desired; after a bit of trial and error.  I don't understand what the "2:-" and "3:-" do/mean.  Can someone explain.

```
#!/bin/bash
pid=$(ps -ef | grep java | awk ' NR ==1 {print $2}')

count=${2:-30}  # defaults to 30 times
delay=${3:-10} # defaults to 10 second
mkdir $(date +"%y%m%d")
folder=$(date +"%y%m%d")
while [ $count -gt 0 ]
do
    jstack $pid >./"$folder"/jstack.$(date +%H%M%S.%N)
    sleep $delay
    let count--
    echo -n "."
done
```

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html  look for `${string:position:length}`

Comment: You don't get it Marc B

Comment: This question is more useful since google do not search :-

Answer (score 115, accepted):

It's a parameter expansion, it means *if the third argument is null or unset, replace it with what's after* :-

```
$ x=
$ echo ${x:-1}
1
$ echo $x

$
```

There's also another similar PE that assign the value if the variable is null:

```
$ x=
$ echo ${x:=1}
1
$ echo $x
1
```

Check http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Comment: Rather than "void", it's more accurate to say "unset or null".

Comment: The link is dead (possibly temporarily) - there is a mirror here: https://github.com/rawiriblundell/wiki.bash-hackers.org/blob/main/syntax/pe.md#use-a-default-value