# Meaning of ${PYTHON:-python} in shell script and how to change

Tags: python, bash, shell

I am trying to export a Mercurial repo to GitHub using [hg-fast-export](https://github.com/frej/fast-export/) and Github Bash for Windows. It choked on the line `from mercurial import node` because mercurial doesn't support Python 3.

I installed Python 2.7 and tried shebang lines (`#! /Python27/python`) and also `alias python='c:/Python27/python'`. That worked to make `python --version` report 2.7, but the [hg-fast-export.sh](https://github.com/frej/fast-export/blob/master/hg-fast-export.sh) still invokes Python 3 because it contains the line

```
PYTHON=${PYTHON:-python}
```

and that evaluates to Python 3.4.3.

Can you explain how to change this to use a different Python version and also what's going on with the syntax here? I couldn't really Google the meaning of `${}` or `:-` in the shell. Comments on how likely my approach is to get this running on Windows could also be helpful.

Edit: Thanks for the explanations of `:-`. Since the parameter expansion was not needed, I guess the answer to my question was "You have to set `PYTHON='c:/Python27/python'` in the same line as the script for it to use that value." I expected it to be like PATH where you can set it independently for following lines to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usage of :- in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390406/usage-of-in-bash)

Comment: @arco444, that's true as far as it goes, but I'm not sure it addresses the "how to change", for folks who aren't familiar with environment variable usage.

Comment: Aside: I'd create a symlink in `/usr/local/bin`, or another location in the PATH, named `python2`; once you've tested it to work, you can just run `PYTHON=python2 hg-fast-export ...`, and not need to worry about the difference between Windows paths, msys paths, cygwin paths, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intent here is to allow an override to be passed in through the environment.

Thus, if you run at a POSIX shell:

```
$ PYTHON=python26 hg-fast-export ...
```

then in `hg-fast-export` will evaluate `${PYTHON:-python}` to `python26`.

Answer (score 3):

That syntax evaluates a variable, but provides a default:

```
$ foo=123
$ echo ${foo:-456}
123
$ echo ${bar:-456}
456
```

You could try to pass a modified `$PYTHON` to the script:

```
$ PYTHON=c:/Python27/python hg-fast-export.sh ...
```

Comment: Was that last snippet in your original answer? I didn't see it at first (hence my own), and don't know if you answered inside the edit window to have it automatically folded in, or if I just misread.

Comment: I think you added yours while I was still editing mine. :) I initially wanted to answer the part of the question pertaining to accessing vars, and then I realised there might be a workaround the OP could try. You're right, it was an edit, I didn't realise there's a window during which it's not considered one.

Comment: *nod* -- unless someone comments (might also be that upvotes/downvotes count as well, I'd have to find the docs), edits inside a few-minute period of a prior post or edit commit (two? three? five?) are folded in.

Answer (score 2):

This is a way to evaluate and modify text (parameter expansion). Consider this example:

```
$ PYTHON="/usr/bin/python --version"
$ ${PYTHON:-python}
Python 2.7.10
```

`PYTHON` is originally the path and command on how to evaluate the version.

`${PYTHON:-python}` evaluates and runs the former, but it was not empty so the colon dash is not needed

For a detailed breakdown see [What does the colon dash ":-" mean in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27445455/what-does-the-colon-dash-mean-in-bash)